# VideoJS - Change Attribute of Plugin

Tags: javascript, video.js, videojs-overlay

i'm trying to change an attribute of a videojs plugin (marquee overlay plugin) after running in JS.
the code is as follows:

```
if (msg.length < 2) {
    $('.vjs-emre-marquee').hide();
} else {
    $('.vjs-emre-marquee').show();
    player.marqueeOverlay({
    contentOfMarquee: data.responseText,
    });
}
```

however, this just creates a new overlay object.
any way to change the existing one?

Answer (score 0):

Updating - found the answer for this specific plugin:
$(".js-marquee").html(data.responseText);